# exceljs conditional formatting of cells

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I am using exceljs to create an excel workbook.  A sheet will have a range of A1:AR106.  My data objects will contain 3 properties (numtype, nummax, nummin).  Only properties nummax and nummin will appear on the sheet.  I can successfully create the workbook with formatting but I am not able to make conditional formatting of individual cells work.

I would like to color cells depending on the value of numtype.  For example, if numtype = 'abc', the nummin cell will be lightblue and nummax will be lightred.  So i would expand this for other possible values of numtype and set colors for nummin/nummax accordingly.

I found documentation for exceljs at https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#conditional-formatting
but I have not been able to make conditional formatting of cells work for me.

```
        worksheet.addConditionalFormatting({
          ref: 'A3:AR106',
          rules: [
            {
              type: 'containsText',
              operator: 'containsText',
              text: 'abc',
              style: {fill: {type: 'pattern', pattern: 'solid', bgColor: {argb: '#98b8eb'}}},
            }
          ]
        })
```

Does anyone have an example I could follow that would lend itself to what I have described?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work for me either. Were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use priority option

```
worksheet.addConditionalFormatting({
      ref: 'A3:AR106',
      rules: [
        {
          priority:1,          // add this
          type: 'containsText',
          operator: 'containsText',
          text: 'abc',
          style: {fill: {type: 'pattern', pattern: 'solid', bgColor: {argb: '#98b8eb'}}},
        }
      ]
    })
```